# Unable to install mobile-fu rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, mobile

I was trying to install mobile-fu plugin in my application. I fired a command

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/brendanlim/mobile-fu.git
```

and i get following error

```
    ==>LogInitializer: Starting initialization of loggers
==>LogInitializer: Loading xml config
==>LogInitializer: Xml config Loaded
==>LogInitializer: Loggers initialized
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `open'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `block in connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:87:in `timeout'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:166:in `transmit'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:60:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:31:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient.rb:68:in `get'
    from /home/aashish/wellcore_fit/wellcore_fit/acms/main/dynamic_service_plane/app/requesters/ws_client.rb:20:in `get'
    from /home/aashish/wellcore_fit/wellcore_fit/acms/main/dynamic_service_plane/app/requesters/cache_manager.rb:8:in `getAllUrlsForDynamicPlane'
    from /home/aashish/wellcore_fit/wellcore_fit/acms/main/dynamic_service_plane/config/initializers/init.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `block in load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:200:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:200:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    from /home/aashish/wellcore_fit/wellcore_fit/acms/main/dynamic_service_plane/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

i am not understanding where i am going wrong. Please comment if know anything about this.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: in error part initial logs are of logger initialization so ignore them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This file: `/home/aashish/wellcore_fit/wellcore_fit/acms/main/dynamic_service_plane/config/initializers/init.rb` wants to connect to the web to get some URLs but cannot for some reason. It's the getAllUrlsForDynamicPlane method in your cache_manager.rb file.

Comment out whatever is doing the web connection on init, and you should be able to proceed.

Comment: Thanks. I got that fixed but still i am not able install any plugin on my machine... :( Strange no error thrown !